# How fst on function that output tuples works in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, tuples

I'm trying to figure out how tuples work in Haskell, and how you can get certain data values from tuples.

I have the following code, and this runs properly, and prints out the tuple output I expect:

```
test :: Integer -> (Integer, Integer)
test c =  function(1, c)
```

However, when I try to get just the first value from the tuple, as shown below,

```
test :: Integer -> Integer
test c = fst function(1, c)
```

I get the following error

- Couldn't match expected type '((Integer, Integer) -> Integer, b0)' with actual type '(Integer, Integer) -> (Integer, Integer)'

Any help or advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Test` cannot be a name of a function. Function names start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was using lowercase functions, I just changed it to "Test" for examples sake.

Answer (score 3):

You simply got the syntax wrong.

`f x` means "*apply (call) function `f` to argument `x`*".

Similarly, `f x y` means "apply function `f` to arguments `x` and `y`".

Your example `function(1, c)` means "*apply function `function` to argument `(1, c)`*". Don't let the absence of a space before the opening paren fool you: `(1, c)` does not mean "*call function with two arguments*" (as it would in, say, C or Java), it means "*make a pair with two components, `1` and `c`*". This pair is then used as a single argument for `function`.

Now, the next expression, `fst function (1, c)` means "*apply function `fst` to two arguments - `function` and `(1, c)`*". This is obviously not what you meant. Instead, you meant to first call `function` with argument `(1, c)`, and then pass the result as argument to `fst`. To express this, you may use parentheses:

```
test c = fst (function (1, c))
```

But of course this is now too many parentheses. To avoid the extra pair, you may use the ubiquitous operator `$`:

```
test c = fst $ function (1, c)
```

This operator doesn't really do anything interesting, it just applies the function on the left to the argument on the right:

```
f $ x = f x
```

The value of this operator is that it makes it possible for the function application to not have the highest precedence, and thus get rid of extra parentheses.

Comment: Alternatively, `(fst . function) (1, x)`. While it does have that extra pair of parentheses, which is one reason why I too prefer the solution with `$`, it does avoid the messy nesting, and demonstrates that if the OP wants to do this a lot they can define a new function as `fst . function`. (And that last sentence is one reason why `function` is not a good name for a function...)

Comment: Oh, it wasn't actually called function, I just changed it to function for examples sake.

Comment: Thank you Fyodor and Robin. Fyodor, what I ended up doing with it was change it to 

         test c = fst d where d = function(1, c); 

I was mostly trying to figure out why my initial implementation wasn't working, and you have answered that.

Comment: My answer did not rely on it to be called `function`. The whole explanation still stands, regardless of what it's called.

Comment: Oh, sorry, that comment was meant for Robin.